# Stop multiple sessions accessing the same file simultaneously

Tags: php, gd

Is it possible to lock a file to stop it being opened while GD library is accessing it?

What I am looking to achieve is similar to a database 'serialzable' level of isolation... I want to ensure that only one session/user can access an image at a time to stop a 'dirty read'.

My application allows users to add an image of choice to a bigger image.

**for example**

- the big image is empty
- Raj & Janet upload their images
- Raj's session opens the big image.
- 1 ms later Janet's session
  opens the big image.
- Raj's session add's his image and
  saves the big image
- 1 ms later Janet's session
  adds his image and saves its version
  of the big image.
- As a result Raj's image is not in
  the final image as Janet's version
  overwrote it.

I hope that makes it clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [flock](http://php.net/flock). You can either lock the file you're working with, or create a "lock file" somewhere else in the filesystem which all your scripts check for.

Comment: It looks perfect, my only fear is what if somehow a file becomes locked forever.. Is there a way to safeguard against this?

Comment: The lock is released when the file is closed so the only trouble would be if your process hangs without closing (i.e. becomes a zombie process).